# Go - Modify JSON on the fly

Tags: json, go

Considering the following input:

```
"object": {
  "array": [
    {
      "element_field_1": some_value_1,
      "element_field_2": some_value_1,
      ... // More unknown fields
    },
    ...
  ],
  "object_field": foo,
  ... // Some more unknown fields
}
```

I need to iterate over every element of the array, modify fields 1 and 2 and then output the JSON object. Here's what I have for now, but it is far from being valid Go code:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Transform the request's body to an interface
    j := getDecodedJSON(r)

    // Iterate over every element of the array
    for i := 0; i < len(j["object"]["array"]); i++ {
        rewrite(j["object"]["array"][i])
    }

    // Encoding back to JSON shouldn't be a problem
}

func getDecodedJSON(r *http.Request) map[string]interface{} {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var j map[string]interface{}
    if err := dec.Decode(&j); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return j
}

func rewrite(element *map[string]interface{}) {
    element["element_field_1"], element["element_field_2"] = lookupValues(element)
}
```

Basically the error is:

```
invalid operation: j["object"]["array"] \
(type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

but of course there's a more conceptual mistake on my approach.

Writing a `struct` that details the content of the input isn't really an option, since I don't know the JSON keys beforehand.

How can I do this "the Go way"?

**EDIT**: This is the actual use case:

- I have two web services that need a "translator" between them.
- Service 1 makes a request to the translator, where a couple of fields are modified, everything else is left intact.
- Then the translator takes the modified JSON and replicates the request to service 2.

In other words, this translator acts like a man in the middle for both services. Go seems to be a good option for this given its fast startup times and fast JSON handling.

I don't think it makes sense to detail every JSON field in a Go struct, since I only need to change a few fields. I'm willing to make a tradeoff in efficiency because of reflection (parsing to a `map[string]interface{}` should be slower than using a full-blown struct), in exchange of making the code more generic to variations of the JSON input.

Comment: Do you know the types of the unknown fields?

Comment: @inf no, not really. But if you hace a workaround that involves knowing the types then I guess I could work something out

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
j["object"]["array"][i]
```

to

```
j["object"].(map[string]interface{})["array"].([]interface{})[i]
```